# Keys within dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm currently forming a program that takes every single winner of the US World Series(baseball) and forming 2 dictionaries with them.  My choice of code is to follow the parameters of the objective, (no key;value for 1904 or 2015 as there was no world Series)  I think my issue is a lack of understanding of dictionaries, if you think I misused a function or value Id appreciate the help.  Feel free to chastise, I wish to learn.

```
def main():
    start=1903
    input_file=open('WorldSeriesResults.txt','r')
    winners=input_file.readlines()
    year_dict={}
    count_dict={}
```

Okay so I have read the file and created the dictionaries, year_dict for year:winner and count_dict for winner:win count.

```
    for i in range(len(winners)):
        team=winners[i].rstrip("\n")
        year=start+i    
        if year>= 1904:
            year += 1
        if year>= 1994:
            year += 1
        year_dict[str(year)] = team
        if team in count_dict:
            count_dict[team] += 1
        else:
            count_dict[team]=1
```

Okay, so I created a range loop to facilitate the processing of the dictionary.  The file(now list) to be stripped line by line and connected to a corresponding year (1-A,2-B,3-C etc) while skipping over the 1904 and 1994 as need be.  Then using the search `search` function I count how many times each team appears in the list, then add that number to the count_dict respectively.  At this point I thought that I had formed each dictionary perfect, I performed a `print` on both of them at this point and it looked like I'm right.

```
    while True:
        year=int(input("Enter a year between 1903-215 excluding 1904 and 1994: "))#prompt user
        if year == 1904:
            print("There was no winner that year")
        elif year == 1994:
            print("There was no winner that year")
        elif year<1903 or year>2015:
            print("The winner of that year in unkown")
        else:
            winner=year_dict[year]
            wins=count_dict[winner]
            print("The team that won the world series in", year, "was the", winner
            print("The", winner, "won the world series",wins, "times.")
            break
```

Here I prompted the user for input.  I wanted this to be the next key.  The user gives an input and if its valid it should be the key used to get an answer but the key doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
winner=year_dict[year]
```

by

```
winner=year_dict[str(year)]
```

because you used strings to populate your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is simple, the `keys` of both of your dictionaries `year_dict` & `count_dict` are in `string` format, so when you query your `dict` in the `while` loop you need to convert them back to `string`, as follows:

```
while True:
        year=int(input("Enter a year between 1903-215 excluding 1904 and 1994: "))#prompt user
        if year == 1904:
            print("There was no winner that year")
        elif year == 1994:
            print("There was no winner that year")
        elif year<1903 or year>2015:
            print("The winner of that year in unkown")
        else:
            winner=year_dict[str(year)]
            wins=count_dict[str(winner)]
            print("The team that won the world series in", year, "was the", winner
            print("The", winner, "won the world series",wins, "times.")
            break
```